# how should I cover all case responses in python from the user for my code?

Tags: python

```
secret_word = "girrafe"
guess = ""

while guess.upper!= secret_word: 
    guess = input("Enter guess: ")

print("You win!")
```

Comment: I think the problem you might be having is that you've missed the parentheses off `.upper`; it should be `guess.upper()` (it's a method, rather than an attribute). You presumably also need to do `secret_word.upper()` for the check to work properly.

Comment: secret_word = "giraffe".upper()

guess = ""

while guess != secret_word: 

    guess = input("Enter guess: ")

print("You win!")

okay I just tried to do this, but now only the upper cases are stopping the loop

Comment: hi harsh, could you please add some text accompanying your question to describe what you are trying to do in some detail? it can often help you just to put your goal into words, too, but it would be helpful for anyone trying to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

So far your code seems nice, I think you forgot to add the parentheses to call the function and upper should be lower in order to match your word. I also added a redundant phrase to lower your secret in case it is dynamic.

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""

secret_word = secret_work.lower()
while guess.lower() != secret_word: 
    guess = input("Enter guess: ")

print("You win!")
```

This should accept all variations of giraffe, such as:

- giraffe
- GIRAFFE
- gIrAfFe

and so on. You were super close, and make sure to keep trying!

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to coding.